# Appending an array in chrome local storage

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, google-chrome-extension

I am attempting to add `testList` as an element to the `holdTestList` array.

Currently the variables get overwritten every time due to the `sync.set`, however I am trying to store all of them through declaring a new list `holdTestList` and pushing the list obtained through the `sync.get` (`testList`) onto it

**theSettingScript.js**

```
testList.push(var1, var2, var3);
chrome.storage.sync.set({
  list: testList,
}, function() {
  console.log("added to list");
});
```

**theGettingScript.js**

```
window.addEventListener('load', getContents);

var holdTestList = []; // THIS ARRAY IS USED TO STORE THE ORIGINAL LIST AND THE NEW LISTS ADDED TO IT

function getContents() {
  chrome.storage.sync.get({
      list: []
    },
    function(data) {
      console.log(data.list);
      holdTestList.push(data.list); // Putting the new variables into the full array
    });
}
```

Comment: Is your question just "How do I push to an array in chrome storage"?

Comment: The values of the list key are overwritten each time sync.set is performed. I am trying to save the all the values in the new list (holdTestList) even those that have been overwritten.

Comment: To modify an array stored in chrome.storage, you need to `get` the current value, add the new items to that, then `set` it.

Comment: The difficulty here lies with developing a solution that does not overwrite the previous value. The array is updated regularly and its contents must be added to not overwritten